# Restlet proxy generation fails with latest GWT 2.5.0-RC1

Tags: gwt, restlet

Upgraded to GWT 2.5.0-RC1 and the proxy generation for Restlet breaks - I have the latest release 2.1-RC6 in my project. This is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.<init>(com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger, com.google.gwt.core.ext.PropertyOracle, com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator.getSerializableTypeOracleBuilder2_2(ClientProxyGenerator.java:767)
    at org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator.generateSerializers(ClientProxyGenerator.java:569)
    at org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator.generateProxy(ClientProxyGenerator.java:500)
    at org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator.generate(ClientProxyGenerator.java:242)
```

The actual exception gets thrown here :

```
private SerializableTypeOracleBuilder getSerializableTypeOracleBuilder2_2()
        throws Exception {
    SerializableTypeOracleBuilder result = null;

    Constructor<SerializableTypeOracleBuilder> c = null;
    c = SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
            TreeLogger.class, PropertyOracle.class, TypeOracle.class);
    result = c.newInstance(getLogger(), getContext().getPropertyOracle(),
            getTypeOracle());

    return result;
}
```

This following call seems problematic, though I do not see why :

**c = SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
            TreeLogger.class, PropertyOracle.class, TypeOracle.class);**

Somebody got Restlet GWT working with the latest GWT 2.5.0-rc1 ??

**UPDATE: issue opened [#647](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/647)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the problem when using *internal* classes: `SerializableTypeOracleBuilder`'s constructor no longer takes a `TypeOracle` argument, but a `GeneratorContext`.
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.5/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/rpc/SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.java#782

That was already the case in GWT 2.4 though (with the experimental `GeneratorContextExt` instead): http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/rpc/SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.java#747
and even GWT 2.3: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.3/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/rpc/SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.java#763

In other words, Restlet still depends on a 18 months old version, namely GWT 2.2: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.2/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/rpc/SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.java#757

Comment: We'll definitely look into fixing this problem. Stay tuned

Answer (score 2):

I just checked the POMs for the following GWT versions of Restlet:

- http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/gwt/org.restlet/2.2-SNAPSHOT/
- http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/gwt/org.restlet/2.1.1/

and they all have dependencies on version 2.2 of GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The 2.1 and master branches have been updated.

Comment: super.. i will check as soon as possible and provide feedback.